# Pandas apply cumprod to specific index

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe consists of accountId, date , return value of that account on that date, and inflation rate on that date.

Date column demonstrates that how long account has been in system, for example accountId 1 get into system on 2016-01 and get out on 2019-11.

[image]

formula:

```
df["Inflation"] = ((1+ df["Inflation"]).cumprod() - 1) * 100
```

I want to apply this formula to the all accounts but here is the problem.

When I have dataframe consists of only one account it's too easy to apply formula, but when I create a dataframe consists of all users(as I indicated in image) I don't want to apply that formula simply, because every account has different date interval some of them get into system 2016 some of them 2017.

You can imagine like this, let's suppose I have dataframe of all accounts, for example df1 for account1 df2 for account2 and so on. And I want to apply that formula to each dataframe individually, and finally I want to merge all of them and have one dataframe consists of all accounts.

```
df["Inflation2"] = ((1+df.groupby(["AccountId","Inflation"])).cumprod()-1) * 100
```

I tried this code but It gives me error like "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'DataFrameGroupBy'"

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Try wrapping your `groupby` statement within parenthesis: `((1+(df.groupby('species').sepal_length.cumprod()))-1) * 100`.

Comment: @CainãMaxCouto-Silva I already solved it, thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it as follows:

```
df["Inflation"] = df.groupby(["AccountId"]).Inflation.apply(lambda x: (x + 1).cumprod()-1) * 100
```